# Return expression type Promise<T> is not assignable to a type Promise<T>?

Tags: javascript, jasmine, promise, protractor, angular-promise

When I add the javascript doc for the below function, it will give me a warning saying that

```
Return expression type Promise<T> is not assignable to a type Promise<T>
```

Is there anything wrong using the return defer.promise below or do I put the return statement in a wrong place?

```
   /**
     * 
     * @param zname
     * @returns {Promise<T>}
     */
    this.setInfoFromAPI = function (name) {
        var defer = protractor.promise.defer();
        var controlFlow = protractor.promise.controlFlow();
        httpRequestUtility.getRestfulAPIToken().then(function (accessToken) {
            console.log("Access Token is " + accessToken);
            controlFlow.wait(
                getInfoFromAPI(accessToken, name).then(function (returnData) {
                    if (String(returnData).match(httpStatusCodeClientErrorRegx)) {
                        defer.reject('Get Request Error for Zone Info\nResponse Error Code - ' + returnData);
                    } else {
                        setUpInfoFromAPI(returnData);
                        defer.fulfill();
                    }
                }), 60000, 'Get Information').then(function () {
            })
        });
        return defer.promise;
    };
```

Comment: Maybe one of them is an anguarl promise and the other is a protractor promise?

Comment: Btw, avoid the [deferred antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a more explicit `webdriver.promise.Promise` instead of `Promise`:

```
@returns {webdriver.promise.Promise<T>}
```